# util.list not removing all elements

Tags: java, list

I' have very unusual problem with removing elements from List.
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < offers.size(); i++) {
                if(offers.get(i).isSpecialOffer()){
                    offers.remove(i);

                }
        }
  return offers;
```

When I print out offers for testing, I get the right result everyone is true. But when I try to remove elements with true boolean I get wrong result. It prints out offers with false boolean.
I dont know where is the problem?
Thanks for help

UPDATE:
I have function for removing specialOffers from List. I' always get some offers with true value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you include the `remove` (which is currently commented out) *before* you use the `System.out.println` call, then you'll be printing out a *different* value to the one you remove. For example:

Before removal:

```
0 - Foo
1 - Bar
2 - Baz
```

Now if `i` is one, we'll call `remove(1)`, leaving

```
0 - Foo
1 - Baz
```

... so we've *removed* `Bar`, and then we'd *print* `Baz`

You'll also then not check `Baz`, as you'd increment `i` to 2 before testing again.

To do this sort of thing properly, you should either use a loop like this:

```
for (Iterator<Offer> iterator = offers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext() ;) {
    Offer offer = iterator.next();
    if (offer.isSpecialOffer()) {
        iterator.remove(); // Must remove using the iterator!
        System.out.println(offer.isSpecialOffer() + ".." + offer.getName());
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to use the index, ideally work *backwards* to avoid problems:

```
for (int i = offers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Offer offer = offers.get(i);
    if (offer.isSpecialOffer()) {
        offers.remove(i);
        // Use offer, not offers.get(i)
        System.out.println(offer.isSpecialOffer() + ".." + offer.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I use #2 approach. But I don't understand where was the problem. I' was going through whole List and I remove it values with true. Is there some catch with removing? Cause you go top-down with loop?

Comment: @extra90: The first half of the answer explains it. Once you've called `remove(i)`, you're no longer looking at the same value when you use `get(i)` - *and* unless you then decrement `i`, the next value won't be examined in the loop. I suggest you work through it very slowly with a pencil, paper and a concrete example if you still don't quite get it.